# What code gets executed if an exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, logging, exception

```
try
{
    some code
}
catch()
{
    some code
}
finally
{
    some code
}

try
{
    some code
}
catch()
{
    some code
}
finally
{
    some code
}
```

I know that if an exception is thrown in the first try block, then the first finally block will be executed.  What about the second finally block?

Also, if you want to display the message to user when an exception arises, then where you should write that message, and how you should display it?

FYI, I was recently asked these questions in an interview, and was stumped.

Comment: -1: If you want us to take the time to answer your question, take the time to put together a coherent question.

Comment: No sir it is not like that is the only Question my interviewer asked me where i got stucke that's y i put here to understand the concept behind from u intellectual peoples

Comment: I edited the question to remove as much unnecessary narrative as possible.  People like it when you ask just the question, and when the title of your question is as specific as it can be, without being too verbose.

Comment: ok sir in future i will focus on this

Comment: also think about how to answer a question. Numbering the "some code" items would have helped a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy and paste this code into an editor.  Then play around with it, uncommenting *and* re-commenting various lines.  Then compile and run the code.  Keep doing this until you're pretty comfortable that you know *everything* about it.  This is what I recommend you do when you find all such confusing questions, that are simply based on flow control.  That is how you will learn programming flow control.

```
try
{
  Console.WriteLine("try1");
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}
catch(ArgumentNullException e1)
{
  Console.WriteLine("catch1");
  Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
  // throw;
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}
catch(Exception e1a)
{
  Console.WriteLine("catch1a");
  Console.WriteLine(e1a.ToString());
  // throw;
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}
finally
{
  Console.WriteLine("finally1");
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}

try
{
  Console.WriteLine("try2");
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}
catch(ArgumentNullException e2)
{
  Console.WriteLine("catch2");
  Console.WriteLine(e2.ToString());
  // throw;
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}
catch(Exception e2a)
{
  Console.WriteLine("catch2a");
  Console.WriteLine(e2a.ToString());
  // throw;
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}
finally
{
  Console.WriteLine("finally2");
  // throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // Console.WriteLine(((string)null).Length); // Will also throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you wrote, because they are two distinct try blocks (ie one is not contained in the other.) They will both be attempted, the second one after the first finally block is ran.  The second finally block will also be ran.

The second one is situationally dependent, generally, you want to keep your exceptions away from the user as much as possible.  You want your program to be a butler, quiet, out of the way, but there when you need it.  If it were me, I'd probably quietly log the issue, and then continue in the most sane manner possible, unless it was a big issue and you need to notify the user, such as "my ftp client can't find a network connection."  If that's the case, and you're in C#, then I'd suggest taking a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx

Comment: you mean to say that if exception comes in first try block then still the first and finally block and other finally block corresponding to the secon try catch block will execute too ..please let me know ....also i want to know if is it correct to display some message to user insted of exact exception in the corresponding catch block please brief me on this...  i am also using logger LOG4Net but i want to display the appropriate message on some exception where shud i display it

Comment: message box class is for the windows application but how o display in the web appliations

Comment: you mean that if exception comes in first try block then first try block will be executed as well as the second also but how come second is corresponding to the second try block

Answer (score 1):

*when I say program blows up, the app dies and raises a runetime exception because it was not caught, and no further code is executed.

```
try
{
    some code1 //always executes this, on exception goto code2
}
catch()
{
    some code2 //if exception was caught do this, if exception occurs in this code program blows up
}
finally
{
    some code3 //always executes this, if exception happens here, program blows up
}




try
{
    some code4 //if program has not blown up at this point, execute this. on exception goto code 5
}
catch()
{
    some code5 // if exception was caught do this. if exception occurs in this code, program blows up.
}
finally
{
    some code6 //if program has not blown up by now, always do this.
}
```

Common code paths would be:
1-3-4-6 for a no exceptions found
and 
1-2-3-4-5-6 if an exception happened in 1 & 4
other cases are rarer (your error handling is broken)